# Can't convert string to numeric

Tags: r

I imported a csv file from excel.  All the Revenue columns are importing as string.  I want them to be numeric.

I thought it would be as easy as `a$Revenue <- as.numeric(a$Revenue)`, but this coerces NAs into all the cells, wiping out the data.  So the column does convert to numeric, but I lose all the data.

Is there another technique?

Comment: please provide `str(a$Revenue)`

Comment: Rev         : chr  "" " -   " "" "13,333.00" ...
 $ Rev         : chr  "" " -   " "" "13,333.00" ...
 $ Rev         : chr  "" " -   " "" "13,333.00" ...
 $ Rev         : chr  "" " -   " "" "15,467.00" ...
 $ Rev         : chr  "" " -   " "" "15,467.00" ...
 $ Rev         : chr  "" "3,667.00" "" "15,467.00" ...

Comment: str(a$Revenue) = chr [1:4284] "" " -   " "" "13,333.00" "" "" "" "" "" "" ...

Comment: You have commas and other stuff in your vector, do `a$Revenue <- as.numeric(gsub("[,-]","",a$Revenue))`

Comment: And don't post additional information into comments, rather in the question itself

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I would agree with the removal of the commas, but not necessarily the hyphens--don't know if there are any negative values in there! Anyhow, the values that are `" - "` should be converted to `NA` by coercion....

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you probably right, I just saw these `"-"` and wasn't sure how `as.numeric` will treat them as there no reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

When you load the data try setting `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv` function, and then try again.

Comment: It looks like their values are already character format, so how do you propose that this solution be applied to address their problem?

Comment: I had the same problem last week and this is what solved it, so don't think it hurts to try.